# (process:10728): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_get_state: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed

Tags: opencv

I am using cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
When opening the camera to record video, the program will work but he prompts me ((process:10728): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_get_state: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed
) I don't know what the reason is, is it because of a problem with your cmake or a problem with the installation?

Comment: is it related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/21785123, or https://stackoverflow.com/q/51303321?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue in version 3.4.4, compiled with gstreamer support. Syntax "cv2.VideoCapture(0)" just stopped working. I had all gst-* libraries installed, so most of answers wasn't helpful. But finally changing VideoCapture argument to full device path ("/dev/video0") helped.

Comment: You're right ! I was using cv::VideoCapture::open(int index)and it sometimes worked, sometimes not ... I followed your advice and used cv::VideoCapture::open(device_filename) and it seems to wrok 100% of time ! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_V4L)
```

From this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53543167/)

it works in my project

Comment: Of course, it also works when error is caused on local video reading