# gstreamer critical error when trying to capture video using webcam python opencv

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, gstreamer, odroid

i'm trying to take a video with webcam using opencv and python with a simple code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
print('cap.isOpened')
if cap.isOpened():
    print ('cap is opened')
    while(True):
        re,img=cap.read()
        cv2.imshow("video output", img)
        k = cv2.waitKey(10)&0xFF
        if k==27:
            break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

it's working fine if i try to play an existing video such as .mp4 file. but when i try using a webcam i got an error

> GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_get_state: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed
>   cap.isOpened

for more information i'm using odroid xu4 with ubuntu 16.04, webcam i use logitech c170 ( it work properly in webcamtest and using guvcview) thought it doesn't workon cheese and camorama.

need help about this please..

Comment: In terminal enter: `python -c "import cv2; print(cv2.getBuildInformation())" | grep -iP "(v4l|ffmpeg)"`. What is the output?

Comment: @zindarod this is the error i got when i type what you say on my terminal
`Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`

Comment: also i try to see the cv2.getBuildInformation() in the ffmpeg keyword and this is the value :
` Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      YES (ver 2.2.4)
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (ver 57.89.100)
      avformat:                  YES (ver 57.71.100)
      avutil:                    YES (ver 55.58.100)
      swscale:                   YES (ver 4.6.100)
      avresample:                YES (ver 3.5.0)
`

Comment: Does installing `gst-libav` solve this?  See [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/195351/) OpenCV Q&A post.  Also, what's the OpenCV version?

Answer (score 1):

The following workaround has a reasonable chance of working:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_V4L)
```

The ability to select backends was added in OpenCV 3, see the `VideoCapture()` [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#ad890d4783ff81f53036380bd89dd31aa).

The workaround switches the backend to **V4L** (from default GStreamer) for my OpenCV 3.4.4 build with GStreamer support on a 16.04 box.  Here the output of the question's code with workaround after `export OPENCV_VIDEOIO_DEBUG=TRUE`:

```
[ WARN:0] VIDEOIO(cvCreateCameraCapture_V4L(index)): trying ...

[ WARN:0] VIDEOIO(cvCreateCameraCapture_V4L(index)): result=0x20b1470 ...

cap.isOpened
cap is opened
```

If the workaround does not work for you, you can check whether your OpenCV build supports `V4L` using `print(cv2.getBuildInformation())`.  Here the relevant section for my build:

```
Video I/O:
  DC1394:                      YES (ver 2.2.4)
  FFMPEG:                      YES
    avcodec:                   YES (ver 56.60.100)
    avformat:                  YES (ver 56.40.101)
    avutil:                    YES (ver 54.31.100)
    swscale:                   YES (ver 3.1.101)
    avresample:                NO
  GStreamer:                  
    base:                      YES (ver 1.8.3)
    video:                     YES (ver 1.8.3)
    app:                       YES (ver 1.8.3)
    riff:                      YES (ver 1.8.3)
    pbutils:                   YES (ver 1.8.3)
  libv4l/libv4l2:              NO
  v4l/v4l2:                    linux/videodev2.h
```